# Flush in entity causes infinite loop (Doctrine 2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

there are two entities:

```
A: which will auto update something on B
B
```

in A there is a preupdate:

```
@ORM\PreUpdate
public function asd()
{
    foreach (\Doctrine\Repository\B::getInstance()->findxxxx($sdf) as $x)
    {
        $em->remove($x);
        $em->flush(); *******
    }
}
```

I traced the SQL log:

```
Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation.php: 1116
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker.php: 102
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 1064
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 384
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php: 356
Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation.php: 1116
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker.php: 102
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 1064
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 384
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php: 356
Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation.php: 1116
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker.php: 102
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 1064
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php: 384
Doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php: 356
Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation.php: 1116
```

so it turned out the line with ******* causes this infinitive loop. Im inside a transaction. I know its not much, but can someody help me?

Comment: Does B have some properties that are references of A ? Also, even if that is surely not the cause of the problem, flush inside a loop should be avoided as possible. You need only one flush at the end, but if you have a lot of entries, look at [batch processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) .

Comment: I was inside a transaction. By checking ->getConnection()->isTransactionActive() and missing flush() when its active seems to be OK

Comment: perfect ! It was very specific .

Comment: seriously? Or irony? :) I mentioned in my started post that Im inside transaction

Comment: lol ... I was serious. I totally skipped the line about you're in transaction, otherwise I would give it the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using remove-> inside a PreUpdate and that is the likely cause of your problem.

See the [documentation on PreUpdate](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate), note the section down the bottom "restrictions for this event".

You should look at using a different event like onFlush or prePersist. In your case I would write that as an [event listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events), not as an entity method as you'll then have access to the unit of work and other useful stuff.

Comment: I was inside a transaction. By checking ->getConnection()->isTransactionActive() and missing flush() when its active seems to be OK

Comment: @JohnSmith Thank you very much, I had the same problem and testing if I was inside a transaction before flushing was the solution ! If you want to, you can write a solution with this and I'll upvote it, thank you so much you don't know how it save me ;)